# Problem with xamarin forms image when removing and adding it from parent layout

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, stream

**Description**
I have created simple Xamarin.Forms sample. In it, I have added an Image and loaded the image as a stream through ImageSource.FromSource() method, then removed and add it to the layout.

**Xamarin.Forms UWP** The image will be disappeared.
**Xamarin.Forms Android** Cannot access closed stream exception throwing.
**Xamarin.Forms iOS** Didn't check yet.

Please find the code snippet below

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ImageException.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
            <Image x:Name="image" />
            <Button Text="Click_Me"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                    VerticalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**C#:**

```
namespace ImageException
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).Assembly;
            string path = "ImageException";

            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{path}.Image.Image.png");
            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainGrid.Children.Remove(image);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Please get the complete sample from below link https://github.com/VigneshRameshh/XamarinFormsImageException

Can anyone suggest how to retain the image after removed and added from the layout?

Thanks in advance,
Vignesh Ramesh.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and could reproduce your exception.

If you want to fix this, you could use the code like below.

```
   Stream stream;
    Assembly assembly;
    string path;
    public Page18()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        assembly = typeof(MainPage).Assembly;
        path = "App14";

        stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{path}.Image.beach.jpg");
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{path}.Image.beach.jpg");
        MainGrid.Children.Remove(image);

        MainGrid.Children.Add(image);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can I know, is there any way to achieve this without making it a global variable?

Comment: YES, but you could not load the image from stream. Set the image from the resource folder of each platform. For more details, check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows